# getting undefined values when doing api call with react and axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

```
const TechnicalAnalysisIndicators = ({ data: initialData, width, ratio }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
    const [rawData, setRawData] = useState();

        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get(
                `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=IBM&apikey=Y7UDL0WGHBS74NXI`
            );
                setRawData(response.data['Time Series (Daily)']);
                console.log(rawData);
           //here raw data is returning undefined value
            
                
            
            
            
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        
            fetchData();
            console.log('raw data'+rawData)
//here also raw data is returning undefined value

    }, [rawData])
```

why raw data is not getting data from api. if i paste the api call url in browser it gives the results
the setRawData(response.data), this line is absolutely correct. I have tested it and it gives response. But How to solve the issue that the state is not updating after getting the value from api?

Answer (score 0):

The API used in this code has a limit of 5 calls per minute. I got this message when I tried this:

`Thank you for using Alpha Vantage! Our standard API call frequency is 5 calls per minute and 500 calls per day. Please visit https://www.alphavantage.co/premium/ if you would like to target a higher API call frequency.`

In addition to that, when you use `rawData` in the dependency array of the `useEffect`, it just keeps fetching forever. To fetch it only once, you need to pass an empty array.

I've formatted the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-monad-ew458z?file=/src/App.js